# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 With Angularjs POST method

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

Im getting this Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 error when trying to do a login with angularjs and php. I have no idea what it means or how to fix it, this is what im doing.

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope,$http) {


$scope.login=function(){

var version = "1.4.0";
$http({
url: 'http://localhost/php/prueba.php',
method:'POST',
data: {
usuario: $scope.usuario,
password:$scope.password,
version:version
},
headers:{
  'Contect-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
}).then(function(response){
console.log(response);
})
}
```

This is my .js file, and in my PHP this is what i have

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//display_errors(1);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
header('Content-Type: application/json');


session_start();

$postdata=file_get_contents("php://input");
$request=json_decode($postdata);
$usuario = $request->usuario;
$password = $request->password;
$version = $request->version;
/*$angular_http_params = 
(array)json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')));


$usuario = $angular_http_params['usuario'];
$password = $angular_http_params['password'];
$version = $angular_http_params['version'];

*/
echo "usuario " . $usuario;
echo " password " . $password;
echo " version " . $version;
?>
```

So i would be glad if someone can help me fix it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) [**Please search before posting**.](/search?q=unexpected+token+u) More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: angular.js:14199 SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at fromJson (angular.js:1345)
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (angular.js:10878)
    at angular.js:10969
    at forEach (angular.js:325)
    at transformData (angular.js:10968)
    at transformResponse (angular.js:11828)
    at processQueue (angular.js:16696)
    at angular.js:16712
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17994)

Comment: Try sending your data back as a json string, not echoed strings. The javascript wouldn't be able to parse what you're echoing currently.

Comment: echo with `echo json_encode($response);` , which is an object that's populated with your data that you need to send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just echo `$postdata` in your PHP script since apparently it is already JSON...

To be sure what data is passed to your client, use your browser's [devtools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see the content of your PHP response

Answer (score 0):

The PHP output should be in json foramt. Anything other than json shouldnt be the output with echo. User json_encode method to construct the output in json.